# Express-validator: How can we validate an Object keys?

Tags: node.js, express, joi, express-validator

I am facing an issue with express-validator to validate an object with two keys. My approach is something like below.

```
  check('contact.code')
    .trim()
    .isNumeric()
    .withMessage('Country code must be numeric.')
    .bail()
    .isLength({min: 1, max: 4})
    .withMessage('Invalid country code.')
    .bail(),
  check('contact.number')
    .trim()
    .isNumeric()
    .withMessage('Phone number must be numeric.')
    .bail()
    .isLength({max: 10, min: 10})
    .withMessage('Phone number must be 10 digits long.')
    .bail(),
```

In **req.body** I'm sending my contact as,
`contact: {"code": "91", "number":"9087654321"}`
But I'm getting the error:

```
{
    "errors": [
        {
            "value": "",
            "msg": "Country code must be numeric.",
            "param": "contact.code",
            "location": "body"
        },
        {
            "value": "",
            "msg": "Phone number must be numeric.",
            "param": "contact.number",
            "location": "body"
        }
    ]
}
```

I already googled it but didn't get any success. Please help me to solve this issue.
Any kind of help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It seems that you are not taking the `params` as a number.Please check it's type and Try it converting to a number.

Comment: As the error message tells you, both values are empty `"value": "",` and thus not a numeric value. Can you verify `req.body` is defined? Have you set up `body-parser`?

Comment: @eol I have already implemented the body-parser and req.body is also defined as rest body keys are validating properly. but only this contact key I have problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Setting up the sanitazion/validation `check` middlewares as follows seems to work fine:

```
const validationResult = require('express-validator').validationResult;
const check = require('express-validator').check;

const express = require('express');
const app = express();
app.use(express.json());

app.post('/test-validation',
  [
    check('contact.code')
      .trim()
      .isNumeric()
      .withMessage('Country code must be numeric.')
      .bail()
      .isLength({ min: 1, max: 4 })
      .withMessage('Invalid country code.')
      .bail(),
    check('contact.number')
      .trim()
      .isNumeric()
      .withMessage('Phone number must be numeric.')
      .bail()
      .isLength({ max: 10, min: 10 })
      .withMessage('Phone number must be 10 digits long.')
      .bail(),
  ], (req, res) => {
    const errors = validationResult(req).array();
    if (errors && errors.length) {
      console.log(errors);
      res.status(400).json({ errors });
    } else {
      res.status(201).end();
    }
  });

app.listen(3000, () => console.log(`Server running`));
```

[Here's](https://codesandbox.io/s/jolly-browser-mwjbg?file=/src/index.js) this code on codesandbox and a sample curl:

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://mwjbg.sse.codesandbox.io/test-validation' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--header 'Accept: application/json' \
--header 'Cookie: __cfduid=d7012caa5f36c195967d2fc26d3b7bd431595933685' \
--data-raw '{ "contact": {"code": "1sdf23", "number":"9087654321"}}'
```

This curl will return:

```
{
    "errors": [
        {
            "value": "1sdf23",
            "msg": "Country code must be numeric.",
            "param": "contact.code",
            "location": "body"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Huge Thanks @eol for your detailed explanation. It worked fine for me